# How to get screen number from saved geometry?

Tags: c++, qt, splash-screen, qwidget

In order to restore last window geometry and state, I'm using a code similar to the one suggested in [this Qt document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/restoring-geometry.html):

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
  QSettings settings("MyCompany", "MyApp");
  settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
  QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
}

void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
  QSettings settings("MyCompany", "MyApp");
  restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());
}
```

Looking at Qt's source code (qwidget.cpp), [`QWidget::saveGeometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) and its sibling `restoreGeometry` are basically a serialization of geometry, screen number and window state.

Now, the application shows a splash screen during start up. I'd like to show such splash screen in the same monitor where the application's window will be displayed. I can set splash screen geometry based on [`QScreen` geometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#geometry-prop), but I need the screen number to complete this code:

```
const auto screens = qApp->screens();
const auto geometry = screens[/* screen number here */]->geometry();
```

How can I get only the screen number from the saved geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to solve the issue creating a fake `QWidget` (never shown), *restoring* its geometry, and using [`QDesktopWidget::screenNumber`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenNumber) to get the monitor where it is supposed to be:

```
int MainWindow::getMonitorToShowSplashScreen() const
{
  QSettings settings("MyCompany", "MyApp");

  QWidget fake_widget;
  fake_widget.restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());

  return qApp->desktop()->screenNumber(&fake_widget);
}
```